# Use LINQ query on left side of assignment in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, syntax-error

I have this simple LINQ query:

```
Dim sourceSect = (From sect In allSections
                  Where sect.ORDER = sourceNode.Index
                  Select sect).Single()

sourceSect.ORDER = targetNode.Index
```

But, if I write it in-line:

```
(From sect in allSections Where sect.ORDER = sourceNode.index Select sect).Single().ORDER = targetNode.Index
```

I get a syntax error from Visual Studio.

Is there any reasonable reason to that? :)

[image]

Comment: Tell us what the syntax error is and we'll be able to give you a better opinion. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe the image I added is more explanatory. If I wrote "Syntax error" is "Syntax error". Full stop.

Comment: And nothing more in the error view?

Comment: Nothing more, neither in the error window.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to add the language to the title, that's why tags exist ;)

Comment: Yes, I know about tags, but I added it to be more specific as, as stated by @BigYellowCactus, in C# this is not an issue! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just write

```
(From sect in allSections Where sect.ORDER = sourceNode.index Select sect).Single().ORDER = targetNode.Index
```

in VB.Net. When using the query syntax, you have to asign the result to a variable first before you can set a property

```
Dim sect = (From sect in allSections Where sect.ORDER = sourceNode.index Select sect).Single()
sect.ORDER = targetNode.Index
```

So, you have to sitck with your code, or use the method syntax (as Tim Schmelter pointed out):

```
allSections.Single(Function(sect) sect.ORDER = sourceNode.Index).Order = targetNode.Index
```

Comment: Thank you! Direct answer, You can't! :)

Comment: Do you know if c# supports that in-line syntax?

Comment: @Meta-Knight He does something with the value retrieved from the Linq query: He's setting a property.

Comment: Actually it is possible using method- instead of query-syntax. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12093224/284240

Answer (score 3):

As sidenote to the accepted answer. It is possible using method syntax:

```
allSections.Single(Function(s) s.ORDER = sourceNode.Index).Order = targetNode.Index
```